# Reboot to secondary user

Tags: reboot, multi-user

So, my kids phone. I need her to be able to reboot the phone and access her account without going through primary account. How can this be done (without rooting). I don't want her be left without call access if her phone reboots or battery runs out.

Why I had to set her as secondary user is that as primary user she was able to circumvent parental control restrictions by creating and switching to guest account before parental control could prevent it. She figured that the lag works for her benefit because she can buffer commands by clicking icons where they will appear while the phone still lags behind.

Comment: Have you password protected the primary user account?

Comment: I got PIN that needs to be entered. Are you suggesting that there could be additional password for primary account access?

Comment: Someone please answer this question I can't find anything on Google.  For Parental apps to work correctly the child needs to run on the secondary account. They need the ability to directly log into the phone. To directly sign into the second account without activating the primary account.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the limiting factor is the [encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based?hl=en#supporting-multiple-users) of the file system. The primary user has be to logged into the device so that the file system is (fully) decrypted. Then the secondary users can also get access.

*"User 0 must log into the device first as it is a special user."*